# When using gsub with [a-zA-Z] in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I've seen this  [a-zA-Z] for the gsub method:

`string.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/,"-")`

where it will find any lower case letters a-z and or uppercase letters A-Z.

My question is why does this a-z work back to back with A-Z :  a-zA-Z ?

Where might I find more info on using [a-zA-Z] in ruby?

Comment: It might help if you could explain what *exactly* in the documentation is unclear to you, so that the Ruby maintainers can improve it for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (the `[]` inside the regex), you can list all the characters you want :

```
/[abcdefg]/
```

to gain some space, you can define a range with an hyphen (`-`) and a letter on each side of the `-` :

```
/[a-g]/
```

Since it's clear that this range is from `a` to `g`, you could write another character directly after :

```
/[a-gm]/
```

You could also define another range :

```
/[a-gm-z]/
```

From the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) :

> A range can be followed by another range, so [abcdwxyz] is equivalent
>   to [a-dw-z]

Note that for your example, you could also use a case insensitive regex :

```
string.gsub(/[a-z]/i,"-")
```

Finally, you can use ranges with [unicode characters](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp) :

```
arrows = /[\u2190-\u21FF]/
"a⇸b⇙c↺d↣e↝f".scan(arrows)
# => ["⇸", "⇙", "↺", "↣", "↝"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use http://rubular.com/ as a reference

> [a-zA-Z] Any single character in the range a-z or A-Z